# jQuery - text insert into textarea only works sometimes

Tags: jquery, textarea

I'm unclear as to why this seems to only sporadically work.

I'm trying to create a button that allows the user to insert text into a textarea, at the location of the cursor. It works so long as they haven't typed in the textarea, but once they type the button ceases to function.

The JS object in the script is using these two methods to split the text, then enter the text it grabs from the clicked button's 'hidden' span.

It should change from this:

```
<newform>
    <box>
    </box>
</newform>
```

…to include extra box tags wherever the cursor might be.

```
<newform>
    <box>
    </box>
    <box> //as if the cursor was here
    </box>
</newform>
```

**The other buttons are currently non-functional.** This is a copypaste from a bigger project.

```
//returns an array where array[0] is text before the cursor
//and array[1] is the text after the cursor
split_at_cursor: function (element) {
    var $el = $(element).get(0);
    var split_pt = $el.selectionStart;
    return [$el.value.substring(0, split_pt), $el.value.substring(split_pt)];
},

//uses split_at_cursor to insert data at the cursor's location
insert_at_cursor: function (element, to_insert) {
    if (typeof (to_insert) !== "string") {
        //this is going to change
        to_insert = '*ERROR*';
    }
    var $el = $(element);
    $el.focus();
    var split_string = fmlpad.split_at_cursor($el);
    $el.text(split_string[0] + to_insert + split_string[1]);
},
```

See the full working non-working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DUjxh/1/)

I've tried some console logging to see what the nature of the issue might be, but it would appear that it always correctly determines where the text *should* go, and what the inserted text *should* be -- it just doesn't always actually do the inserting! :/

Also, I realize I'm probably using a few too many calls to `$(some_element)`, but I'm not sure that the problem lies there, and those will come out once the app gets a little tighter and better defined.

Comment: what you want to achieve?None of Your  button is working,and what behaviour you want on click of New box,New element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'value' of the text area needs to be set, rather than the 'text'.

So you'll have more luck if you use `val()` instead:

```
$el.val(split_string[0] + to_insert + split_string[1]);
```

There still needs to be a bit of work on the cursor position as it jumps after the button press, but I've updated the Fiddle to show this working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUjxh/2/)